# Android App to read current time out loud?

Tags: text-to-speech

I am looking for an Android app that would read out loud the current time. For example if I'm in bed and don't want to open my eyes, I would just press a button or something, and it would read "It is now six thirty four".

Does anyone know about an app that does that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a rather large number of [Speaking Clock Apps](https://market.android.com/search?q=speaking%20clock&c=apps) in the Android Marketplace.

Specifically, the "[Speaking Clock](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.apps.speakingclock&feature=search_result)" app seems to do what you're after, and it's free.